# Convert pdf to jpg using php Magick

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I am looking for a solution to that problem, I am trying to convert pdf to image using php image magic, here is the code, I have tried many solutions but still I am not able to understand why it shows same issue every time

```
 $FILE = realpath(__DIR__ . '/file.pdf');
        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->pingImage($FILE);
        $pageCount = $im->getNumberImages();
        echo $pageCount;
```

If I put jpg file in it, works fine, but if I add **file.pdf** it shows this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system
>   cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794

Note: I have installed ghost script 9.52  64 bit , Imagick 7. something! , I am looking for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a week trying to fix, I discovered that this problem seems to be related to the recents Ghostscript version.

I solved removing it and installing the [version 9.26](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/tag/gs926) after trying all of those.